# Label over a button

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

I'm trying to put a label over a button, but I'm not succeeding...

Here's what I have. I'd like the text "tap to dial" to actually be over the dark grey area, not below it. How do I do that?

On the left side of the image is the view hierarchy, the red things left and right are the button add and button remove, so you get the whole picture.

[image: label over a button]

EDIT: Explanation - The label I'm trying to place over the button is the hint what the button does. The button itself will hold different text contents, thus I need an additional label.

EDIT 2: I don't know why is this question marked with negative votes, why don't people explain that in the comments? Let's pose the question differently: if one wanted to put a label over an image, how would that be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I was looking for was to embed the button and the label in a view. Inside the view they can be positioned to overlap each other, while the view itself can be constrained by auto-layout.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Select both objects in IB (Interface Builder) and then create constraints so they have both have the same vertical and horizontal center. If the text is under the button then select the text view and choose "move to front" from the editor menu.

All that being said, why don't you use a titled button with a gray background rather than trying to put a label on top of your button?

Comment: I'll be putting different text contents to the button, so the label should be a hint on the bottom of the button. So, the label should not have the same center as the button, their bottoms are aligned at the same line, but the button should be continuing behind the label. How can I do that?

Comment: Then do what I described and use constraints to make the button and label have the same vertical and horizontal centers.

Comment: I'm doing that by adding alignment constraints, but the result is not what I want, since: 1) the label covers the whole area of the button, while I need it to cover only a slice of the bottom area and that leads to 2) the button should remain accessible to be clicked on.

Answer (score 0):

A button *is* a label (that is, its title is). So you don't need a button *and* a label; just configure the label *of the button*. The label is the button's `titleLabel` and you can make it do anything a label can do — including consisting of multiple lines, one of which is smaller than the other, as shown here:

[image]

Comment: I explained in another comment that I'm using the label of the button to display different contents, the additional label I'm trying to put over the button is a text hint, what the button does.

Comment: That looks great. How is that property set?

Comment: I was not the first to press the downvote button. Your answer is still not an answer to the posed question, but an attempt to find a different solution to the problem. If I wasn't able to accept that people know more than me, do you think I would have posed a question on StackOverflow? Let me just point out that you are the one boasting with your knowledge. Keep it to yourself, if that makes you happy. Have a nice day.

Comment: Not a "different" solution. A _better_ solution. Putting a label _in front of_ a button is stupid. The button already _contains_ a label. Use it.

Comment: I'm using it, for a different purpose. Nice that you removed your other comments, they weren't providing anything useful to the discussion.